# How to use xsl:round within xsl:when-statement for calculation?

Tags: xslt

I need to add two tags within an `<xsl:when>` statement but get 
Error reported by XML parser:

> Element type "xsl:round" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

I'm using XSLFast for layouts of invoices.
I have an xml-file as a base.
I need to add two tags within a `<xsl:when>` statement but get errors I don't understand.
Error reported by XML parser: Element type "xsl:round" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
`<xsl:when test="Momsprocent = '6.00'">`
`<xsl:round(Apris)*(Momsprocent)>`
`</xsl:when>`
`</xsl:choose>`
```

I want to check if Momsprocent equals 6.00 and in that case multiply it (with 2 decimals) with Apris.

I get error message: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "xsl:round" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: `<xsl:round>` does not exist. Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: i think you use 

<xsl:value-of select="round(Apris*Momsprocent)"/>

Comment: If you always want 2 decimals (incl. trailing zeros), use `format-number()` instead of `round()`. Note that both are **functions**, not **elements**.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too good at this (obviously) so I was told I could use 'round' but didn't know how.
I got it to work but got too many decimals, using xsl:value-of select="round(Apris)*(1.06) " /> .
I therefore replaced round with format-number, but got error "Function
 format-number must have at least 2 arguments" (which michael.hor257k stated - but I don't know how to use it correctly. Have tried <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Apris)* (1.06) " />

Comment: Try `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Apris * Momsprocent, '0.00')"/>`

Comment: @TimC: Thanks especially! That helped me to solve the issue!
But also thanks for the input from the rest of you guys!  Have a great summer!